# Displaying a PHP variable from Database along with HTML

Tags: php, html, image

I want to display a row that contains a text and an image saved with a PHP Variable from a database.
Exemple:

> Row contains: "Some text about something and then `<img src="images/$img">`"

When i try to echo it's displaying like a plain text
Exemple:

> "Some text about something and then `<img src="images/$img">`" thus
>   the $img = "test.png" and image should be echo like `<img src="images/test.png">`

Comment: htmlspecialchars() ?

Comment: @AmitThakur No. You don't get it , $img it contains a text taken from a row  , and when i try to display it in a Img src using echo $content it displays as a plain text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace that substring - but remember to use single quotes not to evaluate `$img` variable.

```
$new_string = str_replace('$img', $img, $old_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is a bad idea

```
<?php $img='a.png'; ?> <img src="images/<?php echo $img?>">
```

Comment: Tried that long ago ,it will not work , it would overwrite and already existing <?php ?> , Exemple <?php echo $content ?> it would be <?php echo "TEXT <img src="images/<?php echo $img?>">" ?>

Comment: It has severe syntax error , Can you update it in your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
$img = 'image.png';
$str = 'Some text about something and then <img src=\"images/$img\">';
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str. "\n";
?>
```

But this is not recommended.

Comment: It's not recommended so i will not use it ,thus i found it very useful.